# What do the chances stand for in the overview tab when using the XVM mod

Tags: world-of-tanks, xvm-mod

In world of tanks when using the XVM mod the overview screen shows two chances listed. "m" and "k" What do these numbers signify?

[image: World of Tanks XVM mod overview]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are two calculated "chances" of winning, using slightly different forumlae.

- K is the more basic of the two, looking only at the efficiency rating and tier.
- M takes more variables into account, such as number of battles and previous winrates.

For M, the forumla is:

> Td=(Tmax+Tmin)/2-T
>
> M=E*(1+R-0.48)*(1+B)*(1+0.25*Td)
>
> Kc=sum(Mci)
>
> Kn=sum(Mpi)
>
> K=Kc/(Kc+Kp)
>
> E=efficiency of player
>
> R=GWR of player
>
> B=normalized number of battles of player (number of battles divided by 100000)
>
> Tmin=min battle tier of current tank
>
> Tmax=max battle tier of current tank
>
> M=effectiveness of player calculated by efficienecy, winrate, battles played and tier
>
> Kc=sum of calculated M for all allies
>
> Kn=sum of calculated M for all enemies
>
> K= win rate

For K, the formula is:

> Kc=sum(Esi*Usi)
>
> Kn=Sum(Epi*Upi)
>
> K=Kc/(Kc+Kn)
>
> Esi allied player efficiencies
>
> Usi allied player tier (Epi Upi being enemy stats)